# Replacing Only Certain White Spaces In a String

Tags: java, split, whitespace

I have string `queryInputNameString` that is equal to `fir, spotted owl` and I'm trying to use `replaceAll()` to remove the white spaces and `split()` to separate the elements in the `inputNameArray` array when a comma occurs.

```
String noSpaces = queryInputNameString.replaceAll("\\s+","");
String[] inputNameArray = noSpaces.split("\\,");
```

So far the above returns:

```
fir
spottedowl
```

but I would like it to only remove the white spaces that occurs immediately before or after a comma and return this:

```
fir
spotted owl
```

How can I make my code ignore white spaces that are not preceded/followed by a comma?

Thanks.

Comment: as i can see call only `split` method would give desired output...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) accepts a regex as argument, you can directly do this:

```
String[] inputNameArray = queryInputNameString.split("\\s*\\,\\s*");
```

Otherwise, if you really want to replace only spaces after a comma, you can use:

```
String noSpaces = queryInputNameString.replaceAll(",\\s+",",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not have to use more sophisticated `regex`.  If you just `split` by comma first and then `trim` each array element you will get the desired result.

This approach might prove to be less effective when dealing with a lot of data.

```
String[] inputArray = queryInputNameString.split(",");
for (int i=0; i < inputArray.length, ++i) {
    inputArray[i] = inputArray[i].trim();
}
```